# How to use single session in many sites

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I have three sites. For example, *www.host1.com*, *www.host2.com* and *www.host3.com*.

You must login (enter username and passsword) to enter the site.

After that, you should be logged in automatically on other sites without login prompt.
Your username and password are same on all sites.

So how to use `session[]` in all sites?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm having some difficulty understanding what exactly you're hoping to do. Could you list off a few things you've already tried and show why they didn't work? Or maybe even just rephrase what you've already written?

Comment: you need to implement a single-sign-on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429166/Basics-of-Single-Sign-on-SSO

Comment: Please put your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implemnet SSO (Single Sign ON )functionality. Which will make you to login only at once.

Its Authentication and Authorization .
Authentication: recognizes who you are.
Authorization: know what you are allowed to do, or what you allow others to do.